# Functional form for differential

Tags: calculus

Suppose I have a function:
$$
y=f(a(c),b(c),c)
$$
Differentiating $y$ with respect to $c,$ one obtains:
$$
\frac{\partial y}{\partial c}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}\frac{\partial a}{\partial c}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial b}\frac{\partial b}{\partial c}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial c}
$$
My question is: why are these derivatives on the RHS additive? In
other words, why is the functional form of $f$ irrelevant here? Why
is this not, say, a generical function:
$$
\frac{\partial y}{\partial c}=g\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial a},\frac{\partial a}{\partial c},\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}\frac{\partial b}{\partial c},\frac{\partial f}{\partial c}\right)
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm confused a little bit with your notation.
If you write a $\frac{\partial}{\partial c}$ you calculate *partial* derivative with respect to $c$. In your question you are asking about *total* derivative with respect to $c$.

Derivative $\frac {dy}{dc}$ is not a general function, because you can consider the next difference
$$
\frac{y(c+t) - y(c)}{t} = 
\frac{f\big(a(c+t), b(c+t), c + t\big)}{t} = 
\frac{f\big(a(c) + a'(c)t + o(t), b(c)+b'(c)t+ o(t), c+t \big)}{t}
.$$
And use the differentiability of $f$. Of course, we assume that $f$, $a$, $b$ are differentiable.

Comment: Given that f(.) is a function of c (albeit indirectly), the total derivative and partial derivative should coincide, no?

Comment: @KwameBrown, may be you are right. I'm used to this notation and strict difference. This helps no to be confused with a such example: f=f(x, y, z) and z=z(x, y). Then partial derivative w.r.t. x and total derivative w.r.t. x must be different.